# Normals transforming, but lighting still weird?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0, shader

I have a basic model viewer which displays a parsed OBJ model. I have a light positioned where the camera is, so the model being viewed is fully lit on one side. For some reason, my transformations aren't doing what I expected in my renderer. When I rotate my model 90 degrees about the x- or y-axis, the mesh is completely dark. But rotate another 90 degrees, and its fully lit again.

Am I doing the transformations wrong? Or are my normals wrong to begin with?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I calculated and applied the proper transform to the normals in my app (transpose of the inverse of the ModelView matrix)

```
Matrix.invertM(mNormalMatrix, 0, mMVMatrix, 0);
Matrix.transposeM(mNormalMatrix, 0, mNormalMatrix, 0);
```

before passing it into my shaders:

```
/*Vertex shader*/
attribute vec3 vPosition; 
attribute vec3 vNormal; 
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix; 
uniform mat4 mMVPMatrix;
uniform mat4 mViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 normalMatrix;
uniform float lightingEnabled;

varying float lightsEnabled;
varying vec3 lightPosEye;
varying vec3 normalEye; 
varying vec3 vertEye;

void main() { 

    /*Calculate normal matrix*/
    vec4 normal = vec4(vNormal, 0.0);
    normalEye = normalize(vec3(normalMatrix * normal));

    lightsEnabled = lightingEnabled;

    lightPosEye = vec3(mViewMatrix * vec4(0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 1.0));

    vertEye = vec3(modelViewMatrix * vec4(vPosition, 1.0));

    gl_Position = mMVPMatrix * vec4(vPosition, 1.0);
}
```

```
/*Fragment shader*/

precision mediump float; 
/*uniform vec4 vColor; */

varying float lightsEnabled;
varying vec3 lightPosEye;
varying vec3 normalEye; 
varying vec3 vertEye;

void main() { 

    /*Light output components*/
    vec3 Ia;
    vec3 Id;

    /*light source components*/
    vec3 La = vec3(0.5);
    vec3 Ld = vec3(1.0);
    /*vec3 Ls = vec3(1.0);*/

    vec3 Ka = vec3(0.3); /*ambient reflectance term*/
    vec3 Kd = vec3(1.0); /*diffuse term*/

    /*ambient light term*/
    Ia = La * Ka;

    float dotProd;
    vec3 lightToSurface;

    if(lightsEnabled > 0.5){
        /*diffuse light term*/
        lightToSurface = normalize(lightPosEye - vertEye);

        dotProd = dot(lightToSurface, normalEye);
        dotProd = max(dotProd, 0.0);
    }
    else {
        dotProd = 1.0;
    }

    Id = Ld * Kd * dotProd;


    gl_FragColor = vec4(Ia + Id, 1.0); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know its been a while, but I've found the solution. The problem was this line in my vertex shader:

```
normalEye = normalize(vec3(normalMatrix * normal));
```

I changed it to:

```
normalEye = normalize(vec3(modelViewMatrix * normal));
```

and everything works fine. Although I have no idea why the second line works when the first one should.